# Find next word in multiple files and replace

Tags: file, python-3.x

I have many files in directory (file1.txt,file2.txt,...) and I want to find the word comes after ('not') and replace it..

```
 directory = os.listdir('/Users/user/My Documents/test/')
 os.chdir('/Users/user/My Documents/test/')
 for file in directory:
    open_file = open(file,'r')
    read_file = open_file.readlines()
    next_word = read_file[read_file.index('not')+1]
    print(next_word)
    replace_word = replace_word. replace(next_word ,' ')
```

I could error

```
next_word = read_file[read_file.index('not')+1]
ValueError: 'not' is not in list
```

any idea!!!!!!

Comment: `read_file` is a list of lines, not a single string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because `read_file` is a list of string, not a single string. The [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method of `list` raises the error you are seeing since no line in your file is exactly "not". The [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) method of string raises an error too, by the way, while [`find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) returns -1.

You need to loop over the lines for your test:

```
os.chdir('/Users/user/My Documents/test/')
directory = os.listdir('.')
for file in directory:
   with open(file, 'r') as open_file:
       read_file = open_file.readlines()

   previous_word = None
   output_lines = []
   for line in read_file:
       words = line.split()
       output_line = []
       for word in words:
           if previous_word != 'not':
               output_line.append(word)
           else:
               print('Removing', word)
           previous_word = word
       output_lines.append(' '.join(output_line))
```

It is important to close files when you are done with them, so I have added the `open` call to a `with` block, which will close the file for you, even if there is an error.

The actual replacement/removal works by first splitting the line into words, then appending the words that do not follow `'not'` into another buffer. When the line is done, it gets joined back into a single string with spaces and appended to the output line list.

Notice that I initialize `prev_word` to `None` only once, before the outer `for` loop, not for each line. This allows lines that end with `'not'` to carry over the replacement to the first word of the next line.

If you want to write the processed file back to the original file, add the following snippet to the end of the outermost `for` loop over the file list:

```
with open(file, 'w') as open_file:
    open_file.write('\n'.join(output_lines))
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for the word "not" and replace the next word with `new_word`.

```
for line in open_file:
    spl = line.split(" ")
    if "not" in spl:
        idx_of_not = spl.index("not")
        spl[idx_of_not + 1] = new_word
    new_line = " ".join(spl)
    print(new_line)
```